# Extracting engrossed text from mingled background

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

**Problem**

I want to extract the text, mostly consists of numbers and "/". The image is a picture of tyres.
The problem is that numbers are engrossed on tyres with similar black color background. I have tried my code with different configurations setting for pytesseract but either nothing appears or very long unnecessary text.

**Code I tried**

```py
import pytesseract as ts
ts.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
import os
from os.path import join
from PIL import Image
ground_path= join(r'C:\Users\happy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data')
files= os.listdir(r'C:\Users\happy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data')
p_squence=[join(ground_path,p) for p in files]
img=Image.open(p_squence[3])
print(p_squence[0])
text = ts.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 5 --oem 2  ')#lang='deu',config='--psm 6 '
#-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789/
print(text)
```

[image: This is the image I am trying to detect from]

**The output I am getting**

```
,,ur,i..,.,_.,_; 4
o k. L R o
NN T N ; ‘
£ RS il AR L
LGN ;___.‘_,.,”.,:;,;,,. ok
B\t ul_: ..3;.,,. ,7; %
! 7 N, ’4 ok f. Y
fi AR .1.‘.;;_.;, " ;.,. h L
/ ‘.,.¢””4h,,_,,.__~,JAHL,“ oM ko' i
7N .,,w.,.:,.,,,.,,_‘,,;_ ! P,, Ty
iy M ) ,,L.,z_ o
0 .
? #.fﬂ,@,. B AN WY R S
Al ,_,xﬂqi,wxﬁt,?fq,, i
p ¥ B ??:,}i.,._. AN
gﬁ%ﬁ.,{. W f,f,p_.f i Heg |
R ‘r%@ ' N ,meﬂ,.&hﬂ_.,.:z y
MR \ e ¥\ e
; ,;,:,.,,,_,,,,_,.._,_&__.%__.ﬁﬁ;f, ol /
;;..y.,w._%,,,,.y,ﬁ.,. b ghﬁwgﬁﬂ, 1 :
) A ?W”..:,,n éf; ,.,.:.,,,.A.v,.;..\"%_:.;,‘ J
v,_v‘.n.n,., P L,aw %o, b y,_n_ ;.,A.»:A..__ﬁ.,._....._?tﬁ: N
,,,..r f,:_ A / ;,Lﬂ, i fi i i [ g
..,./,.@ g 0 ﬁ,.,y_.z.ﬁ ,F W
A A e . ;
Jr/x@.?; yﬁﬂ, , f By .
__ﬂ/y,./m/v,.__.,. aﬁrﬁrﬁﬁ R ?n; i
A W N R 4
3 %%,,,ﬁ..._.,,,..,,,.,.n_.a,w_,,,,_,,ﬂ. B y
LN ,w.a.u, ! ‘,Uwﬁmﬁg g
\ L ..,, . ,»,.‘7; i | y
P S A\ .,:,T.; 3 .:_;mf.,f Y
) mw ,véﬂ«,ﬁ /2&3
S 3 %/rimf«&, iy ¥
...ff..,, § R \;_,,V.,%w,f‘ ! y
f;,f.,.?,/,,: R ;
m%r/ R M .af_n;,,v.aa,iw_,,. Rl ol
MR
```

**What else I have tried**
As you can see in commented line
I have use almost all option for `--psm` 1 to 13 and `--oem` all models
I want to get numbers on tyre.
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you'll almost-certainly need to straighten/unwrap the text before passing it to tesseract

Comment: What does it mean by straighten/unwrap the text . it images actually not a text. or you mean something else.?

Comment: sorry, such that the text doesn't have the curve of the tyre, but is a flat line of text in the expected orientation - I expect this will help tesseract and any other OCR greatly and would make a great first pass (identify tyre curve and undo it) .. you likely also need a good way to make the text quite distinct (for example an edge detect may be needed, though I don't know what is best for tesseract there)

Comment: I think you should try to solve the question using deep-learning methods, maybe an east-text detector might help you.  I don't believe you can solve the problem easily using tesseract. Even if you apply image processing methods such as global, inRange, or adaptive thresholding, you may not achieve the desired result.